# Endomorphism rings of indecomposable modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, representation-theory

This is a more structured reformulation of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3220952/309916).

Let $k$ be a field and $A$ be a commutative $k$-algebra, say $A=k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$, and $M$ be an indecomposable finite dimensional (ungraded or $\mathbf{Z}^n$-graded) $A$-module. Denote by $E=\operatorname{End}_A(M)$ the ring of (homogeneous) endomorphisms of $M$. I am looking for examples (or proofs that this cannot occur) for the following situations:

$$\begin{array}{l|cc}
& \text{$M$ is an $A$-module} & \text{$M$ is an $\mathbf{Z}^n$-graded $A$-module}\\
\hline
k\subsetneq E & \begin{aligned}A&=k[x]\\ M&=k[x]/(x^2+1)\\E&=k[x]/(x^2+1)=k[i]\end{aligned} & * \\
k\subsetneq E/J(E) & ” & ? \\
\text{$E$ is not commutative} & ? & ?\\
\text{$E/J(E)$ is not commutative} & ? & ?\\
J(E)\subsetneq (a\in E\mid \text{$a$ nilpotent}) & ? & ?
\end{array}$$

What I know so far:

- an example for * has already been given in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966646/endomorphism-ring-of-indecomposable-representations).
- The statement in the last row cannot occur if $E$ is commutative.

*Question:* What can be said about the other slots?

Comment: What is $n$-graded?